# serialized_attributes is deprecated without replacement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecation-warning

When I try to Update a model , I am getting the following deprecated warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: `serialized_attributes` is deprecated without replacement, and will be removed in Rails 5.0.
```

And here is my controller sample method

```
def update
@test = Test.unscoped.find(params[:id])
@test.name = params[:test][:name]
@test.abbreviation = params[:test][:abbreviation]
if @test.save
  redirect_to action: :index
else
  @test.errors.delete(:cover_image_content_type)
  flash[:error] = @test.errors.messages.to_yaml
  redirect_to action: :show
end
```

end

Note: Also I have has_paper_trail version: :paper_trail_version in my test model. How to fix this deprecation, which will support when i upgrade to Rails 5?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like upgrading paper_trail to newer version will fix it, based on this [github issue](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/416)

Comment: Ok, but once we upgrade the paper_trail will this deprecation still not be an issue when I upgrade to Rails 5?

Comment: don't think so, the fix is from v4.0 onward and it's supported in Rails 5 https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/commit/3a173678459d01c1b6d4622a5116867205df8788